# Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) just won't turn on

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, intel-core-i7, vt-x, vt-d

I set the VT-x = enabled in BIOS and still Intel Processor Identification Utility reports that VT is not available. VirtualBox refuses to show options for 64-bit OS as well. My processor clearly supports VT. In fact I'd it working with VirtualBox running 64-bit Ubuntu at one point. Then I decided I didn't need it so I disabled it in BIOS and now it just won't come back again!

My processor also supports VT-d and TXT. I tried several combinations of these settings in BIOS without any success. I also tried to enable/disable Hyperthreading, still no success. I've also made sure to remove HyperV component in Windows just in case. I've secured boot disabled and my system is set up for Linux duel boot but I think that shouldn't affect VT-x enablement. My machine is HP Z840.

Anything else I should try?

[image]

Comment: have you considered clearing the CMOS?

Comment: I'd make sure I was running the latest BIOS.

Comment: Can you boot from a Ubuntu Live Disc or Live USB and see what it says? That will tell us if it is a hardware issue or a Windows issue. (You can go [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for instructions to create a Ubuntu Live USB. Then, when you boot from it, choose "Try Ubuntu". Then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118147/829970) for commands to run.)